# Making colons : align vertically in code

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

While learning iOS programming from a book, I notice that for long lines of code like `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, the author tends to break it into 2 lines and align both lines by their colons. How can I achieve that in Xcode4?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is press enter between the two sections. Xcode will do it automatically for you (assuming you're editing an objective-c file).

Comment: oh right, somehow it did not work previously. I also notice that the code autocompletion feature did not work at times (there were no build errors) and I had to restart Xcode to get it to work again